Issue with Using TriggeredSendCustomerKey in SQL Query for _Sent Data View in Salesforce Marketing Cloud
I'm sending emails in SFMC through Automation Studio. I have an automation that runs daily and triggers an email send activity. I'm trying to generate reports using SQL queries from the _Sent data view to track when each subscriber received the email.
In my query, I'm using the TriggeredSendCustomerKey because I guess this is an external key from the email activity in automation studio like this:
SELECT SubscriberKey
FROM _Sent
WHERE TriggeredSendCustomerKey = 'xyz'

However, this query is returning 0 results.
I noticed that in Email Studio, each email send seems to generate a unique JobID for every send, even though the content and configuration of the email remain the same, so I can't use JobID for the query because I would need to change it everyday.
Is there a way to automate this reporting query without relying on JobID or another approach to ensure that the query works across multiple sends of the same email, which generate different JobIDs?
Any advice on how to work around this would be appreciated!

I wasn't aware of Automation Studio generating a different JobId per day, but can I ask why don't you migrate this process to Journey Builder all together? You can trigger it recurringly there, and then you won't have the JobId issue and reporting becomes easier.

You are running into a systemic limit - jobIds are mutable for recurring sendouts (journeys); At least any journey email update (even if you just click save with no change), any Triggered Send "stop-start-publish" will create a new jobId. You would need to establish an Id per sendout that is immutable; SFMC does not come with one out of the box. - so you can relate it to, but cannot inject it into data views.
